# A weaker version of a theorem of P. Hall on noetherianity of $G$-modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-algebras

Recall that a group $G$ is *polycyclic* if it has a finite series of subgroups $G=G_0 \rhd G_1 \rhd \cdots \rhd G_l =1$ for which each factor $G_{i-1}/G_i$ is finite cyclic or infinite cyclic. A group is called *polycyclic-by-finite* if there exists a polycyclic group $H\lhd G$ such that $G/H$ is finite.

Given a ring $R$, a right $R$-module $M$ is said to be *noetherian* if every ascending sequence $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \cdots$ of submodlues of $M$ is finite.

Recall that in the category of groups or modules with homomorphisms, a *retraction* is a homomorphism $r:A\to B$ such that $r(b)=b$, for all $b\in B$, where $B$ is a submodule (or a subgroup) of $A$. Then $B$ is called a *retract* of $A$.

What I want is that under what condition on $G$, a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}G$-module $M$ is r-noetherian? I mean every ascending sequence $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \cdots$ of retracts of $M$ is finite?

A result of P. Hall [Rabinson's book, 15.3.3, p. 446] states that if $G$ is a polycyclic-by-finite group, then the group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ is noetherian. Therefore, finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}G$ is noetherian. But being polycyclic-by-finite is a very strong condition in this situation because it stops every ascending sequence of submodlues of $M$. Is there a weaker version of Hall theorem containing a bigger class of polycyclic-by-finite groups which leads to r-noetherian?

Comment: @YCor You are right. I'll edit it. Thanks for the comment.